# Qt how connect to an existing SQLlite file in android OS?

Tags: android, c++, database, qt, sqlite

I am trying to connect to an existing SQLlite database file in my qt 5.2 project(in Android OS). Where should i save this file to load it using this code:`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("myfile.sqlite");`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should add a database connection using addDatabase with the driver type of QSQLITE and a connection name like MyConnection.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE","MyConnection" );
```

Next you should Set the connection's database name and open it.

```
db.setDatabaseName( "myfile.sqlite" );
if( !db.open() )
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Failed to connect!"), tr("Error connecting to database: ")+db.lastError().driverText() );
}
```

Within your development folder you'll find \android\assets - just put the SQLite database file into that folder and add these to your .pro :

```
deployment.files += myfile.sqlite
deployment.path = /assets
INSTALLS += deployment
```

But the files in assets are readonly. So you should first copy it to some other location:

```
QFile dfile("assets:/myfile.sqlite");
if (dfile.exists())
{
     dfile.copy("./myfile.sqlite");
     QFile::setPermissions("./myfile.sqlite",QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
}
```

Now you can connect to your database as mentioned above.

Comment: I follow these steps, but when I build my android app the sqlite database remove from asset file? and I can't insert or get a value from the database? please help and thanks in advance

Comment: @noname You can also use the Qt Resource system which is a cross-platform solution. By default, all Qt applications can access the contents of a qrc file using the `:/` prefix or the URL scheme prefix, `qrc:`. So all you need is to add the sqlite file to the project resource file and once copy it to some location and use it afterwards

Comment: thank you for your reply, I try this and copy it to its directory, but when I want to insert a value into the database I get this file read-only, although I use setpremissions of my file and the same : attempt this file to read only

Comment: *But the files in `assets` are readonly.* – Even if you only require readonly access you have to copy the file out of the assets location because SQLite can only understand plain filesystem paths, not `assets:/…` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596863))