# How to export SQLite to apk on QT?

Tags: android, qt, sqlite, qml

I am developing an Android app with Qt.First.

I have run it on MinGW then posted it to Android build. My app makes select, insert, update operation on `SQLite` database. This works well in MinGW , but when I exported to Android, there is no effect.

I have copied SQLite file to assets, but I  can't read SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the database file to assets folder, you should also add these to your .pro file :

```
deployment.files += myfile.sqlite
deployment.path = /assets
INSTALLS += deployment
```

But the files in assets are read-only. So you should first copy it to some other location. This could be done once on the first app start:

```
QFile dfile("./myfile.sqlite");
if (!dfile.exists())
{
     QFile::copy("assets:/myfile.sqlite", "./myfile.sqlite");
     QFile::setPermissions("./myfile.sqlite",QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
}
```

You can also use the Qt Resource system which is a cross-platform solution. By default, all Qt applications can access the contents of a qrc file using the `:/` prefix or the URL scheme prefix, `qrc:`. So all you need is to add the sqlite file to the project resource file and once copy it to some location and use it afterwards :

```
QFile dfile("./myfile.sqlite");
if (!dfile.exists())
{
     QFile::copy(":/myfile.sqlite", "./myfile.sqlite");
     QFile::setPermissions("./myfile.sqlite",QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
}
```

Comment: Thanks nejat.I make your suggesstion before :)  this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423152/qt-how-connect-to-an-existing-sqllite-file-in-android-os . But there is no idea

Comment: Nejat I put your code before  database query.Every query this code will take affect.İt is a mistake ?

Comment: @DJ.Yosemite the above code should be even before calling `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase`. The code in the if statement is run once when the app is started for the first time.

Comment: This code run when open app every time. I have put code in main block :(

Comment: @DJ.Yosemite Try to check the returned value of `QFile::copy` to see if the file is copied properly.

Comment: I have now use 'Use Gradle' option.There is an alternative way for this.